# Exporting multiple graphs (SVG) to PDF

Tags: javascript, svg, jspdf, fusioncharts

I'm trying to export multiple graphs (fusion charts XT - rendered as SVG format in web page) to PDF. I learnt fusion charts isn't providing any feature for Javascript graphs. I search for multiple dlls. Finally tried working with jsPDF.js as well as svg_to_pdf.js - but when it comes to rendering multiple graphs - not sure how to proceed. Is there any example online for downloading multiple svg images in a web page to pdf? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple graphs on the same page and want to export them all into one PDF?
If yes, then you can probably consider converting those SVGs into multiple image streams (base64 encoded) using canvas, pass them to the server side, and the server can generate a PDF file containing those image streams.

We have used this method in our own application and I hope it can help you, too.